# ListVIew not updating onRestoreSaveInstanceState

Tags: android, android-lifecycle

Here is my method:

```
@Override
public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    DataBaseHandler handler = new DataBaseHandler(getApplicationContext());

    //set the spinner for measurement type
    Spinner measurementTypeSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.MeasurementTypes);
    ArrayAdapter adapter = (ArrayAdapter) measurementTypeSpinner.getAdapter();
    int typePos = adapter.getPosition(savedInstanceState.getString("measurementtype"));
    measurementTypeSpinner.setSelection(typePos);

    //set the spinner for the measurement unit
    Spinner measurementUnitSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.MeasurementSubValues);
    ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter = (ArrayAdapter) measurementUnitSpinner.getAdapter();
    int unitPos = arrayAdapter.getPosition(savedInstanceState.getString("measurementunit"));
    measurementUnitSpinner.setSelection(unitPos);

    //set the value
    EditText value = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.unit_value);
    value.setText(savedInstanceState.getString("value"));

    /**
     * The list view stuff
     */
    ListView unitsList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.units_list);
    unitsList.setItemsCanFocus(true);
    MeasurementType mType = handler.getMeasurementType(savedInstanceState.getString("measurementtype"));

    //create the converter
    Converter converter = new Converter(MeasurementType.getMeasurementType(savedInstanceState.getString("measurementtype")), savedInstanceState.getString("measurementunit"), savedInstanceState.getString("value"));
    //convert the values
    ArrayList<Unit> convertedValues = converter.convert();

    //set the adapter for the list view
    unitAdapter = new UnitListAdapter(this, convertedValues, mType);
    unitsList.setAdapter(unitAdapter);

}
```

Basically, there is another activity with a list of items and when the user checks one, it updates the database setting an int property to 1, so that when the ArrayAdapter goes through an arraylist it picks up the property as 1 and displays it, instead of 0 in which case it doesn't display it.

Now on pressing the back button, both the spinners are populated with the values I stored, the value for the EditText is restored, but the ListView is not updated, yet when I leave the app and come back in, the value that was checked is there in the list...

This says to me that I might need to do something with onStop() and onRestart() could someone please advice me. The comment saying 'the list view stuff' is where I am trying to update the list view, it just isn't working and when I debug it won't go into the restore method at all, which is confusing.

**EDIT**

```
public class UnitListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Unit> {
    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<Unit> units;
    private MeasurementType type;

    public UnitListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Unit> units, MeasurementType type) {
        super(context, R.layout.unit, R.id.unit_name, units);
        this.context = context;
        this.units = units;
        this.type = type;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.unit, parent, false);
        final TextView unitName = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.unit_name);
        final EditText unitValue = (EditText) rowView.findViewById(R.id.unit_value);
        if(units.get(position) != null) {
            if(units.get(position).getView() == 1) {
                unitName.setText(units.get(position).getUnitName());
                unitValue.setText(units.get(position).getValue().toString());
            } else {
                unitName.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                unitValue.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        }

        return rowView;
    }

    @Override
    public void add(Unit u) {
        units.add(u);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public void clear() {
        units.clear();
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return units.size();
    }

}
```

As asked for. Sorry about confusion whilst editing.

Comment: I tried doing this: ArrayAdapter<Unit> currentAdapter = (ArrayAdapter<Unit>) unitsList.getAdapter();
        currentAdapter.clear();

        for(Unit u : convertedValues) {
            currentAdapter.add(u);
            currentAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        currentAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); I thought it would be better to get the current underlying adapter, clear its values and just add the new values from the arrayList and then try updating  the list view as such...but it didn't work either.

Comment: I have tried using the invalidate() method as well, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`onRestoreInstanceState()` is not called when the user presses the back button. Most likely you need to move your logic to `onResume()`. I suggest that you read about the Activity lifecycle to get a better understanding about when each of the `onXxx()` methods are called.

Comment: I have just implemented it using onPause and onResume and it works...this is what I was asking...just not very well

Answer (score 1):

After updating the list you need to call notifyDataSetChanged() to repopulate the listview.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged()

Comment: I had actually removed that method from my code because it hadn't worked, I added it back, but like last time, it didn't work. I also added a few log statements to be sure, but none of them were logged...

Comment: also is there a reason when I try to debug, like in my arrayadapter, it doesn't get called?

Comment: It should be getting called, can you post your code for the unitlistadapter?

Comment: I have added the adapter implementation

Comment: @user2405469 What log statements don't get logged? What metod are they in? Also, the same question about your breakpoints...what exactly doesn't get called?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice When I put log statements in the onRestoreInstanceState after creating the converter and calling the convert method and just before updating the list...they don't get called, I am assuming this because nothing is printed. As for the breakpoints, I stuck one on where I call  ListView unitsList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.units_list); -- in the same method, it didn't stop at the break point.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice so I was beginning to wonder whether overriding onRestoreInstanceState was the right way to go about it...instead of stopping the activity and starting it again when the user clicks the back button to go back to that activity...

Comment: @user2405469 I suggest you read about the Activity lifecycle. Most likely you need to perform the logic in `onResume()` instead.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice this is what I was asking...whether stopping or in this case pausing this and resuming it was a the way to go.